# Update or delete rows in sql table-per-class hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

What is the best way to update and delete rows in a database that belong to different classes (tables)? Consider tables `person` and `student`, where student is a subclass of person and student.id refers to person.id

```
person:  id | name
student: id | number
```

**Delete**

If, for example, all people with a student-number smaller than 100 and an empty name have to be deleted, one could use a query like

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE person.id IN (
    SELECT person.id FROM person JOIN student ON person.id = student.id
        WHERE person.name = "" AND student.number < 100
)
```

and use cascade delete to automatically delete student entries. Is there a way to improve this?

**Update**

For updating this problem becomes harder because there is no way to update the two tables simultaneously. For example, how can the following ***pseudo*** query be executed:

```
UPDATE person JOIN student ON person.id = student.id
    SET person.name = "test", student.number = 0
    WHERE person.name = "" AND student.number > 10
```

A possible way would be to (in php and within a transaction) retrieve all matching row id's with a select query and then update each table separately using a modified where clause: `WHERE id IN ($list_of_ids)`. This, however, seems like a suboptimal solution. How can this be solved efficiently?

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName How would I use triggers for updating those tables?

Comment: do you have to have reduntant data in your database? seems it's more like a design flaw than an actual sql question

Comment: @MichaelKunst What redundant data are you referring to? I am considering any type of data where different tables represent class hierarchies, the examples are just for illustration. I updated the question a bit in the hope to clarify.

Comment: For Update - you could make two UPDATEs in one stored procedure